# 単純なコピー＆ペーストがうまく実行されない

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

会社名を「（東京都）元ダミーデータ」A1:A5列までをコピーしたいです。
のちに他の機能と連携させたいので、「データ整理」ファイルで「会社名入力」関数を実行させたいのですが、実行されません。
COMPANY関数はほぼ想定通りに動いています。
DATA関数の中でCOMPANY関数を動かすためには、どうすればよいですか？

[image: 会社名元データ]

[image: こんな風にコピー＆ペーストしたい]

```
function  Data() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
COMPANY


  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);

}
```

したが、単体でなら実行できる関数です。

```
function COMPANY() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  let  v = i+11;
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A' + i).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'（東京都）元ダミーデータ\'!A' + i).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B' + v).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'（東京都）元ダミーデータ\'!A' + i).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  
  //会社名をB1:B10と、B12:B22まで出力
   } 
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Scriptにおける、「関数」の扱い方を最低限のレベルでも知る必要があります。

関数には「定義」と「実行」の2フェーズ必要ですが、それぞれ「どのように記述する必要があるのか」が決められています。

### 関数の「定義」

大雑把に書くと下記のような文法で記述することが出来ます。

- `function funcName(/* 仮引数 */) { /* 処理 */ }`
- `const funcName = (/* 仮引数 */) => { /* 処理 */ }`

今回で言えば、`function COMPANY ～`として関数の定義そのものは正しく行えています。
（※当たり前ですが、そうでなければGASの画面上で実行すら出来ません）

### 関数の「実行」

GASにおける関数の実行は、`funcName(/* 実引数 */)`の書式が必要です。
仮に引数を必要としなくとも、最低限`()`がなければ「関数の実行」とはみなされません。

### 元のソースについての言及

```
function  Data() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
COMPANY


  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);

}
```

`DATA()`の処理の過程で、「関数の実行」を意図しようとした`COMPANY`という行がありますが、これは「関数そのものを参照」しているだけであり、**「関数の実行」を意味していません。**
関数の実行を意味していない以上、`COMPNAY`関数内に記述されている処理は当然ながら実行されません。

### どうする必要があるのか

ここまで出ている通り、`COMPANY`の記述をしているタイミングで関数の実行をしたいのであれば、下記のようにする必要があります。

```js
function  Data() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //スプレッドシートをGASで使う宣言
  COMPANY();

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('現在実行した結果出力されるシート'), true);

}
```

Comment: 関数名を書いただけでは関数を参照しているのみであり、関数を実行するためには、引数そのものはなくても、();の書式を書く必要があるのですね
ありがとうございます！